# How do I make the foreach function so that

Tags: javascript, html, dom, input, foreach

I have html code with input as follows,

`I want to directly record the value of each input element,

Previously I have tried to make the javascript code below, but I think this is too long, maybe there is an easier or shorter way, sorry I'm still a beginner in this matter.

```
  <div class="btn_container">
    <div class="btn_container_btn">
      <a href="/" class="btn">BUTTON LINK</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="editor">
    <div class="editor_box">
      <div class="selection">
        <p>Text</p>
        <div class="edit_row">
          Size <input type="number" name="">
        </div>
        <div class="edit_row">
          Color <input type="color" name="">
        </div>
        <div class="edit_row radius">
          <span>
            <input type="number" name="" class="paddingTop">
          </span><span>
            <input type="number" name="" class="paddingLeft">PADDING<input type="number" name="" class="paddingRight">
          </span><span>
            <input type="number" name="" class="paddingBottom">
          </span>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="editor_box">
      <div class="selection">
        <p>Border</p>
        <div class="edit_row">
          Color <input type="color" name="" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="edit_row radius">
          <span class="gap">
            <input type="number" name=""><input type="number" name="">
          </span>
          <span>
            RADIUS
          </span>
          <span class="gap">
            <input type="number" name=""><input type="number" name="">
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="edit_row radius">
          <span> <input type="number" name=""></span>
          <span class="gap"><input type="number" name="">STROKE <input type="number" name=""></span>
          <span><input type="number" name=""></span>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="editor_box">
      <div class="selection">
        <p>Border</p>
        <div class="edit_row">
          Color <input type="color" name="" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="edit_row radius">
          <span class="gap">
            <input type="number" name=""><input type="number" name="">
          </span>
          <span>
            RADIUS
          </span>
          <span class="gap">
            <input type="number" name=""><input type="number" name="">
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="edit_row radius">
          <span> <input type="number" name=""></span>
          <span class="gap"><input type="number" name="">STROKE <input type="number" name=""></span>
          <span><input type="number" name=""></span>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

`

I am trying to create the following DOM, Can anyone help me simplify this javascript code. I think this is too long. Sorry I'm still a beginner. Thank you for the help.
`

```
"use strict";
const rdhBtn = document.querySelector(".btn");
const container = document.querySelector(".btn_container");

const input = document.querySelectorAll("input");
const output = document.querySelectorAll("output");

let style = document.createElement("style");

for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  input[i].addEventListener("input", () => {
    const css = {
      font: {
        size: input[0].value,
        color: input[1].value,
        padding: {
          1: input[2].value,
          2: input[3].value,
          3: input[4].value,
          4: input[5].value,
        },
      },
      border: {
        color: input[6].value,
        radius: {
          1: input[7].value,
          2: input[8].value,
          3: input[9].value,
          4: input[10].value,
        },
        width: {
          1: input[11].value,
          2: input[12].value,
          3: input[13].value,
          4: input[14].value,
        },
      },
    };
    style.innerHTML = `
      .btn {
        background: #4D1CDA;
        border-width: ${css.border.width[1]}px ${css.border.width[3]}px ${css.border.width[4]}px ${css.border.width[2]}px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: ${css.border.color};

        border-radius: ${css.border.radius[1]}px ${css.border.radius[2]}px ${css.border.radius[4]}px ${css.border.radius[3]}px ;
        font-size: ${css.font.size}px;
        padding:  ${css.font.padding[1]}px ${css.font.padding[3]}px ${css.font.padding[4]}px ${css.font.padding[2]}px
      }
      a{
        color: ${css.font.color};
        text-decoration: none;
      }
    `;
  });
}

// let fontSize, padding, radius, border, fill, borderColor, color, shadow, style;

// fontSize = 16;
// padding = 17;
// radius = 23;
// border = 2;
// fill = "#eee";
// borderColor = "#000";
// color = "#fff";
// shadow = {
//   x: 2,
//   y: 2,
//   blur: 2,
// };
// for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
//   input[i].addEventListener("input", () => {
//     // Text Output
//     output[0].innerHTML = input[1].value;
//     output[1].innerHTML = input[2].value;
//     output[2].innerHTML = input[3].value;
//     output[3].innerHTML = input[4].value;
//     output[4].innerHTML = input[5].value;
//     output[5].innerHTML = input[6].value;
//     output[6].innerHTML = input[7].value;
//     output[7].innerHTML = input[8].value;
//     output[8].innerHTML = input[9].value;

//     // Value
//     fontSize = input[0].value;
//     padding = input[1].value;
//     radius = input[2].value;
//     border = input[3].value;
//     fill = input[7].value;
//     borderColor = input[8].value;
//     color = input[9].value;
//     shadow = {
//       x: input[4].value,
//       y: input[5].value,
//       blur: input[6].value,
//     };
//     style.innerHTML = `
//       .btn {
//         background-color: ${fill};
//         font-size: ${fontSize}px;
//         padding: ${padding}px;
//         border-radius:  ${radius}px;
//         border: ${border}px solid ${borderColor};
//         box-shadow: ${shadow.x}px ${shadow.y}px ${shadow.blur}px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
//       }
//       a{
//         color: ${color};
//         text-decoration: none;
//       }
//     `;
//   });
// }
container.appendChild(style);
```

`

Comment: JS is the wrong tool to write iterations for CSS. Look into SASS or LESS.

Comment: Thank you in advance..I want to try to make a tool to auto-generate buttons, this is just a protype, I'm also using sass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

****Edits**** :
To answer to the question "How I can simplify my style object", and to the solve the problem of dynamic properties (because, for the moment, if you change the values with the arrows, that will not update the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) because of my optimizations ~ I'm sorry).

The following can be done for the table:

1. Inputs are defined as [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and not as [ListNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).
2. Functions are used on the Array: [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
3. In the end, each event redefines the style object.
4. You can use the properties of the tables to retrieve the elements when applying the style.

So, we've the following code :

```js
"use strict";
const rdhBtn = document.querySelector(".btn");
const container = document.querySelector(".btn_container");

// Array.from(...) allows to transform our ListNode into Array easily.
const input = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input"));
const output = document.querySelectorAll("output");

let style = document.createElement("style");

for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    input[i].addEventListener("input", () => {
        const css = {
            font: {
                size: input[0].value,
                color: input[1].value,
                /*
                * We take the elements of index 2 through 5 using the .slice(...).
                * Then, we scan these 4 elements with the function. .map(...), and we ask the map function to return only the `.value` values of each element. In our case, this will generate an array with only string.
                */
                padding: input.slice(2, 6).map(i => i.value)
            },
            border: {
                color: input[6].value,
                radius: input.slice(7, 11).map(i => i.value),
                width: input.slice(11, 14).map(i => i.value),
            },
        };

        style.innerHTML =
            `.btn {
                background: #4D1CDA;
                border-width: ${css.border.width[0]}px ${css.border.width[2]}px ${css.border.width[3]}px ${css.border.width[1]}px;
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: ${css.border.color};
        
                border-radius: ${css.border.radius[0]}px ${css.border.radius[1]}px ${css.border.radius[3]}px ${css.border.radius[2]}px ;
                font-size: ${css.font.size}px;
                padding:  ${css.font.padding[0]}px ${css.font.padding[2]}px ${css.font.padding[3]}px ${css.font.padding[1]}px
              }
              a {
                color: ${css.font.color};
                text-decoration: none;
              }`;
    });
}

container.appendChild(style);
```

*If ever the values were completely static, which is not the case in your current use, here are the optimizations that could be brought:*

You can simplify your code and optimize it a lot.
To start, you generate a new css object with static values at each iteration in your loop. It is a completely superfluous tecnique, which can be moved outside the loop!

So, you have for the moment, the code below :

```js
const css = {
    font: {
        size: input[0].value,
        color: input[1].value,
        padding: {
            1: input[2].value,
            2: input[3].value,
            3: input[4].value,
            4: input[5].value,
        },
    },
    border: {
        color: input[6].value,
        radius: {
            1: input[7].value,
            2: input[8].value,
            3: input[9].value,
            4: input[10].value,
        },
        width: {
            1: input[11].value,
            2: input[12].value,
            3: input[13].value,
            4: input[14].value,
        },
    },
};

for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    input[i].addEventListener("input", () => {
        style.innerHTML = `
      .btn {
        background: #4D1CDA;
        border-width: ${css.border.width[1]}px ${css.border.width[3]}px ${css.border.width[4]}px ${css.border.width[2]}px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: ${css.border.color};

        border-radius: ${css.border.radius[1]}px ${css.border.radius[2]}px ${css.border.radius[4]}px ${css.border.radius[3]}px ;
        font-size: ${css.font.size}px;
        padding:  ${css.font.padding[1]}px ${css.font.padding[3]}px ${css.font.padding[4]}px ${css.font.padding[2]}px
      }
      a{
        color: ${css.font.color};
        text-decoration: none;
      }
    `;
    });
}
```

But, we can notice that you also create a new style tag at each iteration in your loop when the button is clicked. When we read the code, we can also see that we assign static values to it.

I don’t really understand the purpose of the code, but I play along to optimize the code.

We will therefore move the code assignment outside the function, and put it in a character string to avoid rewriting the value each time.

So, we've that :

```js
const css = {
    font: {
        size: input[0].value,
        color: input[1].value,
        padding: {
            1: input[2].value,
            2: input[3].value,
            3: input[4].value,
            4: input[5].value,
        },
    },
    border: {
        color: input[6].value,
        radius: {
            1: input[7].value,
            2: input[8].value,
            3: input[9].value,
            4: input[10].value,
        },
        width: {
            1: input[11].value,
            2: input[12].value,
            3: input[13].value,
            4: input[14].value,
        },
    },
};

const styleCode = `.btn {
        background: #4D1CDA;
        border-width: ${css.border.width[1]}px ${css.border.width[3]}px ${css.border.width[4]}px ${css.border.width[2]}px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: ${css.border.color};

        border-radius: ${css.border.radius[1]}px ${css.border.radius[2]}px ${css.border.radius[4]}px ${css.border.radius[3]}px ;
        font-size: ${css.font.size}px;
        padding:  ${css.font.padding[1]}px ${css.font.padding[3]}px ${css.font.padding[4]}px ${css.font.padding[2]}px
      }
      a{
        color: ${css.font.color};
        text-decoration: none;
      }
    `;

for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    input[i].addEventListener("input", () => {
        style.innerHTML = styleCode;
    });
}
```

In closing, we can do even better. As previously stated, you will assign a new `style` code in your element each time someone presses a key on their keyboard in an `input` element that is `focus`.

However, this will not change the behavior of the page, apart from overloading its RAM, and the calculations made to update the DOM (RIP low power computers).

So, when the user fills in the text, delete all the events on the input page.

To do this, we need to move the run function during the event to an external function (to be able to delete the input event).
This gives the final following code:

```js
"use strict";
const rdhBtn = document.querySelector(".btn");
const container = document.querySelector(".btn_container");

const input = document.querySelectorAll("input");
const output = document.querySelectorAll("output");

let style = document.createElement("style");

const css = {
    font: {
        size: input[0].value,
        color: input[1].value,
        padding: {
            1: input[2].value,
            2: input[3].value,
            3: input[4].value,
            4: input[5].value,
        },
    },
    border: {
        color: input[6].value,
        radius: {
            1: input[7].value,
            2: input[8].value,
            3: input[9].value,
            4: input[10].value,
        },
        width: {
            1: input[11].value,
            2: input[12].value,
            3: input[13].value,
            4: input[14].value,
        },
    },
};

const styleCode = `.btn {
        background: #4D1CDA;
        border-width: ${css.border.width[1]}px ${css.border.width[3]}px ${css.border.width[4]}px ${css.border.width[2]}px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: ${css.border.color};

        border-radius: ${css.border.radius[1]}px ${css.border.radius[2]}px ${css.border.radius[4]}px ${css.border.radius[3]}px ;
        font-size: ${css.font.size}px;
        padding:  ${css.font.padding[1]}px ${css.font.padding[3]}px ${css.font.padding[4]}px ${css.font.padding[2]}px
      }
      a{
        color: ${css.font.color};
        text-decoration: none;
      }
    `;

function onInput() {
    style.innerHTML = styleCode;
    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        input[i].removeEventListener("input", onInput);
    }
}

for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    input[i].addEventListener("input", onInput);
}

container.appendChild(style);
```

*PS*: For those who would like to realize a completely dynamic code, and much shorter, do not hesitate to play with the properties of the custom attributes in your HTML DOM, and also the default values (to avoid undefinedpx after the css is generated).
You will only modify one part of the css object, and no longer the object itself, and you will be able to target the css code more easily by directly modifying the properties with for example:

```js
rdhBtn.style.padding = `${css.font.padding[0]}px ${css.font.padding[2]}px ${css.font.padding[3]}px ${css.font.padding[1]}px`;
```

Hoping to have answered your question correctly, I wish you a pleasant session of code!

Have a nice day.

Comment: Thank you very much in advance.,
How to simplify this?
font: {
        size: input[0].value,
        color: input[1].value,
        padding: {
            1: input[2].value,
            2: input[3].value,
            3: input[4].value,
            4: input[5].value,
        },
    },



Comment: I will update my answer by explaining how we can solve part of the problem. The style object in question cannot be completely simplified.

Comment: I have tried, but it doesn't work. The css.font.size value I tried in the console.log doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t understand the purpose of the initial function. I changed my post and it should solve the problems.

Comment: Final code like this [link]https://jsfiddle.net/mhmdridho1499/jk9m5vL6/2/

Comment: No problem! If you find my answer satisfactory, you can validate it with the checkMark icon next to it.